# proving a group is soluble (solvable if you are american)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

1. (7 marks) (a) Show that every group $G$ of order 56 has a normal Sylow subgroup. (Hint: If $n_7 \neq 1$ then show that $n_7 = 8$ deduce from this that $G$ has 48 elements of order 7, leaving just enough elements for one Sylow 2-subgroup).

If $n_7=1$, the the Sylow 7-subgroup of $G$ is normal. Suppose $n_7=8$. The eight distinct Sylow 7-subgroups are cyclic so that $G$ has at least $6\cdot8 = 48$ elements of order 7. Now $n_2$ divides 7 and is odd, so that $n_2\in \{1,7\}$. If $n_2=7$, then let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be distinct Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$. There must exist a non-identity element $x\in P_1$ and $x \notin P_1$, but then $G$ has at least $48+8+1=57$ elements, which is nonsense. Thus $n_2=1$, so that the unique Sylow 2-subgroup of G is normal.

b) Explain why (a) means that every group of order 56 is soluble.

Comment: Outside of the US it's really called "soluble"? As in "dissolves in a solvent"? Why on earth is it called that?

Comment: Does anyone who isn't a (finite?) group theorist in England say "soluble" anymore? 0:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theorem you need is

> Every finite $p$-group is solvable.

and

> If $N\lhd G$, $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable, then $G$ is solvable.

So from part (a), you have proven that $n_7=1$ or $n_2=1$.
Let $P\in Syl_7(G)$.
Then $P\lhd G$. Also note that $P$ is $7$-group and $G/P$ is $2$-group.
Hence $P$ and $G/P$ are solvable, so is $G$.
If you let $Q\in Syl_2(G)$, the same argument follows as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $N \unlhd G$ is solvable and $G/N$ is solvable, then $G$ is solvable. You proved already that there is a $P \in Syl_2(G) \cup Syl_7(G)$, with $P \unlhd G$. Use that a $p$-group is solvable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/780655)

Comment: OK, (a) has been answered to. I was alluding to (b). So?

Comment: Well you have far more experience than me, but my opinion is that this is not a complete answer and would be better as a comment. I suppose you are free to disagree, especially given your rep and such.

Comment: @The Count, edited it slightly to make it more complete.